# Index with pages + story numbers

Tags: indexing, xindy

I have a book with large amount of numbered short stories, and at the end of the book I would like to have the subject index looking somewhat like this:

```
funny ... 100 (222-225, 227), 200 (555)
```

In the brackets are the story numbers.

How can I do it with `xindy` or some other tool?

MWE may be like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
% \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm,anyfontsize}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, FakeStretch=0.97]{Cambria}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Mapping=tex-text, FakeStretch=0.97]{Cambria}
\usepackage[protrusion=all]{microtype}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multind}
\makeindex{subj}
\makeindex{name}
\newcommand{\subj}[1]{\index{subj}{#1}}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{\index{name}{#1}}
\newcounter{story}
\setcounter{story}{1}
\newcommand{\newstory}{%
    \pagebreak[3]%
    \vspace{1cm}%
    \noindent\textbf{\thestory. }\stepcounter{story}\ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}
\newstory
Была одна история…
\subj{funny}

\newstory
Была другая история…
\subj{funny}

\newstory
Была третья история…
\subj{sad}

\clearpage

\newstory
Была и ещё такая история…
\subj{funny}

\clearpage
\printindex{subj}{Тематический указатель}

\end{document}
```

Compiled by

```
xelatex mwe
xindy -M texindy -M page-ranges -L russian -C utf8 -o subj.ind subj.idx
xelatex mwe
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Where do the story numbers come from? Please add the code of a complete (=compiling) small document that shows the book setup, contains a sufficient number of (dummy) stories, etc.

Comment: @gernot Added mwe. Story numbers come from a simple counter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: I changed the definition of `\thepagestory`, because the old definition could sometimes give the wrong page number (around a page break).**

I changed the document to use `\usepackage{index}` instead of `\usepackage{multind}` because `index` can have other numbers than page numbers in the index, and `multind` cannot do this. **Note**: with the `index` package, you must run LaTeX twice on your document before running `xindy`.

I also duplicated two stories to get a range in the story numbers. I also made the page numbers bold, but you can easily change that in the `xdy` file.

So here is the document:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
% \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm,anyfontsize}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, FakeStretch=0.97]{Cambria}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont[Mapping=tex-text, FakeStretch=0.97]{Cambria}
\usepackage[protrusion=all]{microtype}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{index}
\makeindex
\newcommand\thepagestory{\noexpand\thepage-\thestory}
\newindex[thepagestory]{subj}{sidx}{sind}{Тематический указатель}
\newcommand{\subj}[1]{\index[subj]{#1}}
\newcounter{story}
\setcounter{story}{0}
\newcommand{\newstory}{%
    \pagebreak[3]%
    \vspace{1cm}%
    \stepcounter{story}\noindent\textbf{\thestory. }\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\newstory
Была одна история…
\subj{funny}

\newstory
Была другая история…
\subj{funny}

\newstory
Была одна история…
\subj{funny}

\newstory
Была другая история…
\subj{funny}

\newstory
Была третья история…
\subj{sad}

\clearpage

\newstory
Была и ещё такая история…
\subj{funny}

\clearpage
\printindex[subj]%{Тематический указатель}

\end{document}
```

This is the xindy style file `stories.xdy`.

```
(require "latex.xdy") 
(require "latex-loc-fmts.xdy") 

(markup-locref :open "" :close "" :attr "hyperpage")


(define-location-class "stories" ("arabic-numbers" :sep "-" "arabic-numbers")
                      :hierdepth 2)

(markup-locref-list            :sep " "
                       :depth 0  :class "stories")
(markup-locref-list  :open " (" :sep ", " :close ")"
                       :depth 1  :class "stories")
;;
;; Put page numbers in bold
;;
(markup-locref-layer :open "\textbf{" :close "}" :layer 0
                       :depth 0  :class "stories")

(markup-range :sep "-" :class "stories")
```

The command to run is, where `storyindex.tex` is my document: (I don't have the russian file so I left out `-L russian` myself)

```
xindy -M stories -L russian -C utf8 -o storyindex.sind storyindex.sidx
```

And this is the resulting index:
[image]

Comment: @pantlmn I made a small but important change, because sometimes the page number could be wrong in the original solution.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do almost the same, but by redefining `\@wrindex` in the `multind` package: `\indexentry{#2}{\thepage-\thestory}`

Comment: Please note: In my solution I put a correction: `\thepage` should be preceded by `\noexpand`, otherwise you might occasionally get the wrong page number. I can give you an example where it goes wrong without it: Put `\usepackage{lipsum}` before `\begin{document}` and `\lipsum[1-4]` after the fourth story, so that story number 5 is at the top of the second page. You will see you get page 1 for the fifth story without `\noexpand` and page 2 with `\noexpand`. I hope this will also work with `multind`.